# Ubuntu fsck + black /purple screen (problem)

Tags: fsck

Yesterday I was working on my computer but it was freezed when I was working. So, I turned off pushing the bottom. When I started again the computer show me a message about the filesystem and I have to run manually fsck. Then I saw some post about it and suggested `fsck -yf dev/sda2` for the first time it works. I continued working, but when I realized that I cannot opened google-chrome-browser, after 4 hours I decided to reboot and that was the last time that I saw my desktop.

I tried a few times with the command I mentioned but, sometimes the screen is completely black or purple. Also I tried using the recovery mode, but is same end.
What I can do? Is strictly necessarily to make a bootable USB with Ubuntu?
By the way, many post said that this a native Ubuntu problem.

More info: I have Ubuntu 18.04, NVIDIA, Intel inside core i7, Asus.

Comment: Can you boot from a USB flash drive with Ubuntu on it? That might help

Comment: I have to use rufus to mount the iso into the usb, but yes. My files don't get lost?

Comment: you'll want to run some commands like fsck to see if there's some kind of correctable error on the disk or partition that you would usually boot from.  Try the lsblk command once you boot to see the names of these devices.

Comment: How can I do that?