# Recovery Ubuntu hard disk info

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, fsck

Some weeks ago I had a problem with my computer and my ubuntu 18.04 crashed ([here I provide some details](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341335/ubuntu-fsck-black-purple-screen-problem)). I don't have success runing the commands to run that ubuntu again. I had too much to do then I decided use another hard-disk and install ubuntu 21.04 on it in order to continue doing my work stuff.

So, I would like to know if there is a way to run or extract my data the old hard-disk, like my logs or configuration files and charged it into this new one hard-disk.

Comment: Yes; there are several possible ways for an amateur to attempt data recovery. Did you look at the other questions under the "data-recovery" tag? Everything you need to know is there.

Comment: If you have the disk containing `18.04` untouched, you can certainly retrieve your data.  Just attach the disk to a working Linux system. `mount` it with an arbitrary name, and then extract the data.